# Python NumPy log2 vs MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm a Python newbie coming from using MATLAB extensively.  I was converting some code that uses `log2` in MATLAB and I used the NumPy `log2` function and got a different result than I was expecting for such a small number.  I was surprised since the precision of the numbers *should* be the same (i.e. MATLAB double vs NumPy float64).

### MATLAB Code

```
a = log2(64);

--> a=6
```

### Base Python Code

```
import math

a = math.log2(64)

--> a = 6.0
```

### NumPy Code

```
import numpy as np

a = np.log2(64)

--> a = 5.9999999999999991
```

### Modified NumPy Code

```
import numpy as np

a = np.log(64) / np.log(2)

--> a = 6.0
```

So the native NumPy `log2` function gives a result that causes the code to fail a test since it is checking that a number is a power of 2.  The expected result is exactly 6, which both the native Python `log2` function and the modified NumPy code give using the properties of the logarithm.  Am I doing something wrong with the NumPy `log2` function?  I changed the code to use the native Python `log2` for now, but I just wanted to know the answer.

Answer (score 8):

No. There is nothing wrong with the code, it is just because floating points cannot be represented perfectly on our computers. Always use an epsilon value to allow a range of error while checking float values. Read [**The Floating Point Guide**](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) post to know more.

**EDIT** - As [cgohlke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453463/cgohlke) has pointed out in the comments,

> Depending on the compiler used to build numpy np.log2(x) is either computed by the C library or as 1.442695040888963407359924681001892137*np.log(x) See [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c.src#L290) link.

This may be a reason for the erroneous output.

Comment: Understood about floating point numbers, but they are all the same types of floating point numbers (i.e. float64) in the calculations. Plus the result error is 4x a float64 eps value and the native log2 doesn't give the same answer for the same floating point type.

Comment: Well, It gives `6.0` as the answer here.

Comment: Both `64` and `6` have exact floating point representations. It appears that NumPy's `log2` is off by `eps(6)`, at least with @Hesse34's version.

Comment: Depending on the compiler used to build numpy `np.log2(x)` is either computed by the C library or as `1.442695040888963407359924681001892137*np.log(x)` See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c.src#L290

Comment: That's a nice find. Mind if I add this to my answer and reference you?

Comment: That would make much more sense, thanks for pointing that out cgohlke.  Just FYI, I am using your prebuilt binaries in this test.  I used the MKL version for Python 3.3 (numpy-MKL-1.7.1.win-amd64-py3.3.‌exe).